# cakephp3 routes SEO-Friendly Routing

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

i need like is.

```
http://localhost:8765/configs/update.json?appid=2
```

this is my router config.

```
Router::scope('/configs', function($routes){
$routes->extensions(['json']);
$routes->connect(
    '/:appId',
    ['controller' => 'Configs', 'action' => 'update'],
    [
        'pass' => ['appId']
    ]
 );
});
```

I mainly refer to the following URL.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#seo-friendly-routing

Who can help me, thank you very much.

Comment: "I need like is" looks nothing like your route config do you mean you want `/configs/2` to act the same as `/configs/update.json?appid=2` ? You may find [restful routes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/routing.html#creating-restful-routes) a better read; there's nothing seo-friendly about the url `/configs/2`.

Comment: you're right, I did not notice a problem with my title. Thank you for your reminder. I'll try this url ，follow official document.  I know this REST routes. do you know where I'm wrong it?